# Is it possible to make it in flash that objects move only on whole pixel width and heigth?

Tags: flash, pixel

My objects sometimes have possition 20.31 for example on x axis, is it possible to make it so they move in a grid maybe, 1px wide grid so there are no decimals in position?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use int() to round your numbers to integers if thats enough for you

let's think about you're setting your object's positions like that

```
x = mousex;
y = mousey;
```

you can use that for this 1 pixel grid

```
x = int(mousex);
y = int(mousey);
```

it is more complicated than this if you wanna use bigger grids... more complicated but not complicated actually...  it's better to tell something about bigger grids after you tell how are you setting your objects positions currently